# RSpec custom partial hash matching

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am currently writing test suite in RSpec.

I read a lot of the documentation and know how to do partial hash mapping.

```
expect(result).to include({key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'})
```

Or if you just want to check for keys:

```
expect(result).to include(:key1, :key2)
```

However I want to do something more fuzzy. I want to check for the type of the value. Something like:

```
expect(result).to include({key1: instance_of(String), key2: instance_of(String)})
```

But RSpec doesn't like that. It will always try to compare 'valuex' to the RSpec ArgumentMatcher (which of course failes).

Is there a way to do this without custom matchers?

Answer (score 3):

Test the specific keys with separate assertions

```
expect(result[:key1]).to be_a(String)
expect(result[:key2]).to be_a(String)
```